# Solution to Schrödinger equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, schrodinger-operators

I asked this question already on stackexchange, but I did not get any resonance at all, so maybe anybody here can give me a few hints about my problem.

My goal is to solve this PDE for $f:[-1,1] \times \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  $$ i\partial_t f(x,t) = -\partial_x^2 f(x,t) + g(t)V(x)f(x,t).$$

I would consider this PDE to be solved if I get two ODEs just depending on either $x$ or $t$. $$f(x,0)$$ is specified a priori and $\int_{[-1,1]} f^*(x,t)f(x,t) dx=1$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Separation of variables seems to fail here and also integral transforms appear to be useless. Despite, I don't want to use perturbative techniques.

I want to have that $g$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function with compact support and $V \in C^{\infty}$.

A simpler setting where an integral transform could maybe work is this one:

If we take $g(t):=\delta(t-t_0)$, where $t_0>0$.

$$ \partial_t f(x,t) = -\partial_x^2 f(x,t) + \delta(t-t_0)V(x)f(x,t).$$

On the other hand, the integral transform(especially the Fourier transform) seems to fail, as the function does not need to be square integrable with respect to time. So, I don't really see if we can do anything about it.

Comment: You will definitely have to impose boundary conditions at $x=\pm 1$ to obtain a well defined problem and have $\int|f|^2$ preserved. The second version could of course be reduced to $i \dot{f}=Hf$ with a time-independent $H$, plus a condition at $t=t_0$ (so this boils down to understanding the spectral theory of $H$), but I have a feeling that's as far as you can go in general.

Comment: Put differently, I don't think the product structure $g(t)V(x)$ helps a lot, as there are no obvious relations between the spectra/eigenfunctions of $-D^2+cV$ for different $c$'s.

Comment: Here is the earlier question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844601/solution-to-schrödinger-equation-partial-t-fx-t-partial-x2-fx-t-d  Normally you should wait more than 9 hours before crossposting - some of the math.SE people are sleeping or busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Christian Remling that the product structure of your potential $V(x,t)=g(t)V(x)$ is not helpful in general, but it would help if $g(t)$ is a  monotonically decreasing function of time, see [this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313020436/http://pdf.easechem.com/pdf/32/d34de190-5a35-4f5e-83d0-51d030387708.pdf) by T.J. Park (2002).

> Only a few
> time-dependent systems have been reported to be analytically solved
> whose potentials are constant, linear, and quadratic functions of
> coordinate with arbitrary time-dependences. Here we show that time-dependent potentials of any
> coordinate-dependence can be solved exactly if the
> time-dependence is monotonously decreasing. We do this by a unitary
> transformation of the wavefunction and variable transformations to
> change the Schrödinger equation to be time-independent in new
> variables. These variables are then determined by solving a set of
> simple differential equations.

Comment: The links seems to be no longer working.

Comment: perhaps https://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO200202727434516.pdf ?

Comment: I replaced the link with a link to the Wayback Machine

Answer (score 0):

In the linear case, $V(x)=x$, the Schrodinger equation can be solved by Lewis-Riesenfeld approach. See http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs12648-013-0322-4 as well as http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0309174 and references cited therein.

Some other cases is considered in http://journal.kcsnet.or.kr/main/j_search/j_abstract_view.htm?code=B021211&qpage=j_search&spage=b_bkcs&dpage=ar (Exactly Solvable Time-Dependent Problems: Potentials of Monotonously Decreasing Function of Time, by Tae Jun Park).